# ¿Cómo mando un valor de una función de Javascript a otra con un valor de password?

Tags: javascript, html

Aquí convierto un input en forma de password con un checkbox para mostrar y ocultar

```
function showPassword() {
    var x = document.getElementById("valor");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Al pasarlo en una tabla se pone en texto plano en vez de ponerlo como contraseña.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var param = $("#param").val();
        var valor = $("#valor").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td>" + valor + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    });

    $(".delete-row").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();

    });
});
```

Como puedo hacer para que el valor se mande como password y se imprima como tal en vez de texto plano?

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Este post te puede ayudar: [Table cells as a password type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789667/table-cells-as-a-password-type)